# Bad link to editor toolbar image on new user restrictions page

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, privileges-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not available images in stackoverflow help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100997/not-available-images-in-stackoverflow-help-pages)

I'm seeing a missing image on a link in https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user

Under the section: How do I add images and links to my posts?
Beside the bullet item: • the editor toolbar button
The link currently points to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpE5T.png

Which gives an image not found error.
I suspect it should point to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7DAA.png

**[EDIT]**

Here's what I see:

[image: Screen capture of missing image]

I'm curious whether any other users are seeing this issue.
I'm able to pull other images from that site.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me... They shouldn't be the same image; one is used for creating links, the other is used for adding images.

Comment: Ah, ok.. retract my suggestion of where it should point to, then. :)

Comment: I've successfully wget'd the file from another host, so this appears to be some sort of CDN issue... unsure why I can't pull it from this host, especially since C3zkF.png comes down fine.

Comment: Please note the same problem here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100902/image-is-broken-on-the-close-question-page Adding more comments: this seems to be very sporatic by user. Siva has seen the same prob on close question page while others do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to see the image in uri https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpE5T.png

[image]