# Not available images in stackoverflow help pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, broken-link

At pages "[Remove new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user)" () and "[Vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up)" two images (one by page) has "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available" status.

Answer (score 4):

We have found and replaced all of the links to i.imgur.com in the privilege wikis with i.stack.imgur.com.  This will go out with the next build.